# How to match certain strings using regex regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following string:

```
string = @"
/SQL "\Geneva\GenevaAfterTaxExtracts" /SERVER SMAMSQL2602A /CHECKPOINTING OFF 
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::Portfolio].Properties[Value]";"2504,2505,2506,2507,336,339,340,343,344,345,346,348,349,350" 
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::FirstMonthEnd].Properties[Value]";"8/31/2013" 
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::LastMonthEnd].Properties[Value]";"8/31/2013" 
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::Files].Properties[Value]";"Valuations" /REPORTING E"
```

I would like to match and nextMatch as the following:

```
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::Portfolio].Properties[Value]";"2504,2505,2506,2507,336,339,340,343,344,345,346,348,349,350" 
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::FirstMonthEnd].Properties[Value]";"8/31/2013" 
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::LastMonthEnd].Properties[Value]";"8/31/2013" 
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::Files].Properties[Value]";"Valuations"
```

I'm using the following:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\/SET ([^\/]+)");
Match match = re.Match(command);
```

The first one and last one work fine, but the date ones get truncated before '/' as shown bellow

```
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::FirstMonthEnd].Properties[Value]";"8

/SET "\Package.Variables[User::LastMonthEnd].Properties[Value]";"8
```

How can I change Regex(@"/SET ([^/]+)") that way it matches on the dates as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag your questions with the language you're using.

Answer (score 2):

If they are separate lines

```
/SET.*
```

If they are on the same line

```
/SET.*?(?=/[a-zA-Z]+|$)
```

---

```
List<String> output=Regex.Matches(input,regex)
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(x=>x.Value)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! on the same line worked. I was stuck for hours! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\/SET (.+?)(?=( *\/[a-z]| *$))");
```

Comment: Anirudh's solution /SET.*?(?=/[a-zA-Z]+|$) worked fine for me. Thanks for the quick replay!